# Starting a Windows application in the background

Tags: .net, c#, winforms

I have a Windows application written in C# using winforms. I want to make sure that whenever someone starts it from any other application using process.start the UI is not shown and the application should start silently.

I do not have control over other applications so I can not use:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; 
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exeFolder"].ToString(); p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal; 
p.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exeName"].ToString(); 
p.Start();
```

Comment: Windows Service can be useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. I am sorry to not have provided my solution earlier. I have resolved the problem and have documented the solution for someone else to use in future.

You can find the solution [here](http://anujyadavcse.blogspot.in/2012/01/create-background-taskbar-application.html).

How To
·         Create a new windows project and delete the default form (Form1).
·         In Program.cs create a new class and inherit it from Form.
·         Please refer the code below.
·         Now change the Main method. In Application.Run change the startup object from Form1 to ApplicationStartUp.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using BackgroundApp.Properties;

namespace BackgroundApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>


   /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ApplicationStartUp());
    }
}

public class ApplicationStartUp : Form
{
    private NotifyIcon trayIcon;
    private ContextMenu trayMenu;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
        trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", OnExit);
        trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        trayIcon.Text = Resources.TrayIcon;
        trayIcon.Icon = new                            Icon(global::BackgroundApp.Properties.Resources.IntegratedServer, 40, 40);
        trayIcon.ContextMenu = trayMenu;
        trayIcon.Visible = true;
    }

    //Ctor
    public ApplicationStartUp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Visible = false;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Release the icon resource.
        trayIcon.Dispose();
        Application.Exit();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            // Release the icon resource.
            trayIcon.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, when an application is started from another, it is started with no arguments.

You could therefore have your application check the starting arguments. If there is no argument, you start it with the window hidden. If there is an argument, start the application with the window visible.

You'll have to modify the `main` method in your **Program.cs** file to look like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

static class Program
{
    // get the current process
    var thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    // file name of this process
    var procFileName = new System.IO.FileInfo(thisProc.MainModule.FileName).Name;

    // look for all with the same file name as this one.
    foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessesByName(
                         procFileName.Substring(0, procFileName.LastIndexOf('.'))))
    {
        // if there is another process with the same file name and a different id
        // it means there is a previous instance of the application running
        if (proc.MainModule.FileName == thisProc.MainModule.FileName &&
            proc.Id != thisProc.Id)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An instance of this application is already running.");
            return; // stop running this instance
        }
    }

    static internal bool useGui;

    /// <summary>The main entry point for the application.</summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        useGui = (from arg in args where arg.ToLower() == "/gui").Any();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Then in the event handler for `Form1.Show` make the form visible or not by reading the value of the `useGui` variable like so.

```
private void Form1_Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = Program.useGui;
}
```

### Edit

Setting the form's `Visible` property in the `Form.Load` event does not hide it. You should rather set it in the `Form.Shown` event handler like the updated code does.

Here are a couple of things you should consider if you intend to give the application this functionality.

1. Starting the application 'normally' will cause it to flash and get hidden. This may make a user start the application several times without knowing it. It is therefore recommended to check if a copy of the program is running already in the `Program.Main` method.
2. The application will be hidden while running. If, therefore, you do not put in code to close it after it has completed all of its operations, the user will have to kill the process in order to terminate it.

**Edit 2**
Updated code for `class Program` with a fix for issue #1.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application have to have a GUI at all?

If not, you could re-write it without one. If you then need the configuration GUI you could write a second app which connects to the first to configure it.

Comment: Actually I can not create a windows service and I need my application to keep running that is why I am opting for gui application. I also need this application to be able to show messages via messagebox and balloon thus I am creating winform application.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with arguments to your application.  The other application starting up *your* application could pass in an argument such as `/noui`.  Or you could default to no gui and use an argument such as `/ui` to start with a gui.  Since you have no control over the calling application the second option may be what you go for.

Comment: I am ok with no ui as default and always. But how should I achieve that in c#.

Comment: I would not start up the main UI form at all.  Rather use some other controlling class that contains your main behaviour and use this same class in your main form.  So you branch in your `static void Main()`: `if (useGui) { ... show main form... } else { new ControllingClass().Run(); }`

Answer (score 0):

SO if you don't have UI, you have some processing that has do be done anyway, and when appropriate events occur, fire up parts of the UI (you said messageboxes).

My suggestion would be to fire a thread from `Main()` of program.cs - and do the processing in that thread.  Later, when you'll need something shown, you will show it with a code simple as `MessageBox.Show` - because your new thread will have its own message loop.

Don't try to set `visible=false` in your main form because you'll get flashing that will show sometimes.